# redux-saga, websockets and actions queue

Tags: websocket, redux, redux-saga

I have the following problem: server send's messages to the client through websocket. on the client, I need to display this messages to the user. but the problem is that sometimes messages come to fast, and I need to organize some sort of queue and show that messages one after another.

my saga:

```js
import { eventChannel, effects, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga';
import { types, actionCreators } from './actions';

const { call, put, take, race } = effects;

function watchMessages(socket) {
  return eventChannel((emitter) => {
    socket.onopen = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketOpen(e)));
    socket.onclose = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketClose(e)));
    socket.onerror = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketError(e)));
    socket.onmessage = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketMessage(e)));

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  });
}

function* internalListener(socket) {
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take(types.SOCKET_SEND);
    socket.send(data.payload);
  }
}

function* externalListener(socketChannel) {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(socketChannel);
    yield put(action);
  }
}

function* wsHandling(action) {
  const socket = action.payload.socket;
  while (true) {
    const socketChannel = yield call(watchMessages, socket);
    const { cancel } = yield race({
      task: [call(externalListener, socketChannel), call(internalListener, socket)],
      cancel: take(types.SOCKET_CLOSE),
    });
    if (cancel) {
      socketChannel.close();
    }
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga(action) {
  yield takeEvery(types.SOCKET_CONNECT, wsHandling);
}
```

my reducer:

```js
function dataReducer(state = initialStateData, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SOCKET_MESSAGE:
      if (action.payload.channel === 'channel1') {
        return state
          .set('apichannel1', action.payload);
      } else if (action.payload.channel === 'channel2') {
        return state
          .set('apichannel2', action.payload);
      } else if (action.payload.channel === 'channel3') {
        return state
          .set('apichannel3', action.payload);
      }
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

so now, when the new message arrives, I'm changing state and just display it on the screen.

any ideas how I can turn this into the following: put arrived messages into some sort of queue, and show them one by one on screen for some custom time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I did it this way, here is the code, maybe it will be useful for someone

```js
let pendingTasks = [];
let activeTasks = [];

function watchMessages(socket) {
  return eventChannel((emitter) => {
    socket.onopen = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketOpen(e)));
    socket.onclose = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketClose(e)));
    socket.onerror = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketError(e)));
    socket.onmessage = (e) => (emitter(actionCreators.socketMessage(e)));

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  });
}

function* internalListener(socket) {
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take(types.SOCKET_SEND);
    socket.send(data.payload);
  }
}

function* externalListener(socketChannel) {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(socketChannel);
    pendingTasks = [...pendingTasks, action];
  }
}

function* wsHandling(action) {
  const socket = action.payload.socket;
  while (true) {
    const socketChannel = yield call(watchMessages, socket);
    const { cancel } = yield race({
      task: [call(externalListener, socketChannel), call(internalListener, socket)],
      cancel: take(types.SOCKET_CLOSE),
    });
    if (cancel) {
      socketChannel.close();
    }
  }
}

function* tasksScheduler() {
  while (true) {
    const canDisplayTask = activeTasks.length < 1 && pendingTasks.length > 0;
    if (canDisplayTask) {
      const [firstTask, ...remainingTasks] = pendingTasks;
      pendingTasks = remainingTasks;
      yield fork(displayTask, firstTask);
      yield call(delay, 300);
    }
    else {
      yield call(delay, 50);
    }
  }
}

function* displayTask(task) {
  activeTasks = [...activeTasks, task];
  yield put(task);
  yield call(delay, 3000);
  activeTasks = _.without(activeTasks, task);
}

export default function* rootSaga(action) {
  yield [
    takeEvery(types.SOCKET_CONNECT, wsHandling),
    takeEvery(types.SOCKET_CONNECT, tasksScheduler),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can buffer (queue) actions in redux saga using the `actionChannel` effect.

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html#using-the-actionchannel-effect

Then you can read from the channel's buffer at your own speed.

I created a simplified example that listens for messages and displays max 3 at a time, each for 5 seconds. See:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wt8uu?file=/src/index.js

At the bottom, there is a console panel, use it to call `addMsg('Msg: ' + Math.random())` to simulate new socket.io message.